# How to show invariance under additive and multiplicative illumination changes

Tags: computer-vision, mathematical-foundations, digital-image-processing

The task is to "Show that the transformation f -> ((ln f<sub>x</sub>)<sub>x</sub>, (ln f<sub>y</sub>)<sub>y</sub>) is invariant under additive and multiplicative illumination changes."

From my lecture notes, for ((ln f)<sub>x</sub>, (ln f)<sub>y</sub>), I have:

ln (c*f(x,y)) = ln c + ln f(x,y)<sub>x</sub> = (ln c)<sub>x</sub> + (ln f(x, y))<sub>x</sub>
with the note that the first term is 0 if c is global and therefore doesn't depend on x and y. The same can be done for the y-derivative: making the product a summation by taking the log, and then taking the derivative.

Can this also be applied to the function from the task description or do the subscripts change something? Can someone explain it to me? Does this show invariance under multiplicative change? Would this also be sufficient to show invariance under additive change?

Answer (score 0):

$$g:=af+b\to g'=af'\to\log g'=\log a+\log f'\to(\log g')'=(\log f')'.$$

The first differentiation kills the additive constant. The second *logarithmic* differentiation kills the multiplicative constant.

Notice that nothing prevents the first derivative to be negative, causing the logarithm to be undefined.